# Can't toggle Adminlte's navbar on the sidebar in Blazor WebAssembly App

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, blazor, adminlte

I was building a dashboard app with Blazor using [Adminlte template](https://adminlte.io). I created a starter page (from https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/blob/master/starter.html) but the navbar on the sidebar is frozen and can't be toggled.

[image]

Here is an example. https://blazorfiddle.com/s/hypdtify

I wonder if there is workaround for this. Thanks

Comment: Produced the same problem using React.js

Comment: From https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/issues/1570#issuecomment-615841382, Calling `$('[data-widget="treeview"]').Treeview('init')` after `OnAfterrenderAsync` using JSInterop seems to do trick. I am wondering if there is a better solution